# Delete a node(or more nodes) between others in a linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, duplicates, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Hi I'm creating a program for school where I have to:

1. Create structures
2. Create functions to print my linked list
3. Create functions to insert an element to the bottom of the list
4. Delete duplicate elements.

I created all a part the last one step(*delete function*). Can you help me to know what is the right way? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*STRUCTURE*/
typedef struct punto {
    int x;
    int y;
} PUNTO;

typedef struct quadrato {
    PUNTO v;
    int lato;
} QUADRATO;

typedef struct nodo {
    QUADRATO q;
    struct nodo *next;
} NODO;

/*PRINT LIST*/
void stampaQuadrato(QUADRATO q) {
    printf("The square has the side equal to %d and coordinates of the lower left vertex (%d,%d)\n", q.lato, q.v.x, q.v.y);
}

void stampaLista(NODO *head) {
    if(head->next==NULL) {
        printf("List empty!\n");
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
            stampaQuadrato(head->q);
        }
    }
}

/*ADD*/
QUADRATO creaQuadrato() {
    
    QUADRATO nuovo;
    
    printf("Side measurement: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.lato);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Coordinates of the lower left vertex\n");
    printf("x: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.v.x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("y: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.v.y);
    printf("\n");
    
    return nuovo;
    
}

void insert(NODO *head) {
    NODO* nuovoNodo = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    nuovoNodo->q = creaQuadrato();
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        head = nuovoNodo;
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = nuovoNodo;
    }
}

/*DELETE*/
void deleteDuplicates(NODO *head) {
    if(head==NULL) {
        printf("There are no element in the list!\n");
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            if(head->q.lato == head->next->q.lato &&
               head->q.v.x == head->next->q.v.x &&
               head->q.v.y == head->next->q.v.y) {
                   NODO* nodoQuad = head->next;
                   head->next = nodoQuad->next;
                   //head->next = head->next->next;
                   free(nodoQuad);
                   printf("Element deleted!\n");
               } else {
                   head = head->next;
               }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    NODO *head = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    head->next = NULL;
    int scelta = -1;
    
    while(scelta != 0) {
        printf("Choose one\n");
        printf("Press 1 --> See list\n");
        printf("Press 2 --> Insert new square(quadrato)\n");
        printf("Press 3 --> Delete duplicates\n");
        printf("Press 0 --> Stop program\n");
        scanf("%d", &scelta);
        
        if(scelta==1) {
            stampaLista(head);
        }
        else if(scelta==2) {
            insert(head);
        }
        else if(scelta==3) {
            deleteDuplicates(head);
        }
        else if(scelta==0) {
            printf("See you soon ;)\n");
        }
        
        }
    
}
```

Comment: You seem to have written a delete function; what *specific* issues are you having with it?

Comment: my delete function delete ALL elements of the list instead I want only to delete duplicate elements :(. I don't know how to edit it.

Comment: Find duplicates, pass the nodes to a delete function.

Comment: @alex01011 yeah I think there is the right way but i don't understand how to check duplcicates if they are separated by one or more elements

Comment: So what is your problem? ALL?? I just modified it a tiny so I can easily run it it compiler explorer. It works just fine, you just have to implement an extra loop, since now you only checks if 2 neighboring nodes are equal. The simplest if you loop from that node to the end with an another loop and check if any of them are equal similarly to the answer from wajaap.
https://godbolt.org/z/6WYqra81j
Also there is a possible catastrophe, I have marked that with "BOOOMMMM". And your head should be a useful node, not a dummy one.

Comment: can I be so gentleman to write me the delete function plzzz? @simre I'm trying to create an extra loop but I don't understand how.However thank for the advice about don't use head as a dummy node

Comment: @DanieleSadun Sorry, you have all the pieces, and this is your homework. You can do it, and after you did it, you will see that it is not a big deal. But you must suffer a little bit and you will learn it forever. ;)

Comment: @simre yeah now I tried many times and I create an extra loop associating head to a new node.Now it works.For the dummy node in "insert" func I converted head in a node.Is it right?

Comment: Don't put "SOLVED" in your question (I removed it). Instead mark an answer as accepted. If there is no good answer, post one yourself.

Comment: @trincot sorry now I will do in this way

Answer (score 1):

For starters initially the list should be empty. So you have to write

```
NODO *head = NULL;
```

instead of

```
NODO *head = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
```

This while loop

```
int scelta = -1;

while(scelta != 0) {
    //...
}
```

should be substituted for do while loop as for example

```
do
{
    //...
} while ( scelta != 0 );
```

Within the do while loop instead of using if statements it is better to use switch statement as for example

```
do
{
    scelta = 0;

    printf("Choose one\n");
    printf("Press 1 --> See list\n");
    printf("Press 2 --> Insert new square(quadrato)\n");
    printf("Press 3 --> Delete duplicates\n");
    printf("Press 0 --> Stop program\n");
    scanf("%d", &scelta);
    
    enum { Exit = 0, Stampa = 1, Insert = 2, Delete = 3 };

    switch ( scelta )
    {
    case Exit:
        puts( "See you soon" );
        break;

    case Stampa:
        stampaLista( head );
        break;

    case Insert:
        insert( &head );
        break;

    case Delete:
        deleteDuplicates( head );
        break;

    case default:
        puts( "Invalid input. Try anew." );
        break;
    }
} while ( scelta != 0 );
```

The function `insert` is incorrect

```
void insert(NODO *head) {
    NODO* nuovoNodo = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    nuovoNodo->q = creaQuadrato();
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        head = nuovoNodo;
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = nuovoNodo;
    }
}
```

because it does not change the original pointer `head` declared in main because it deals with a copy of the value of the passed pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

Also you forgot to set the data member `next` to `NULL` of the created node.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
int insert( NODO **head ) 
{
    NODO *nuovoNodo = malloc( sizeof( NODO ) );
    int success = nuovoNodo != NULL;

    if success )
    {
        nuovoNodo->q = creaQuadrato();
        nuovoNodo->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = nuovoNodo;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The parameter of the function `stampaLista` should have the qualifier `const`

```
void stampaLista( const NODO *head ) 
{
    if ( head == NULL ) 
    {
        puts( "List empty!" );
    } 
    else 
    {
        for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
        {
            stampaQuadrato( head->q );
        }
    }
}
```

As for the function `deleteDuplicates` then it removes only adjacent duplicated nodes. If you want to remove all duplicated nodes (not only adjacent) then the function can be defined the following way

```
void deleteDuplicates( NODO *head ) 
{
    if ( head == NULL ) 
    {
        puts( "There are no element in the list!" );
    } 
    else 
    {
        for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
        {
            for ( NODO *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
            {
                if ( head->q.lato == current->next->q.lato &&
                     head->q.v.x  == current->next->q.v.x  &&
                     head->q.v.y  == current->next->q.v.y ) 
                {
                    NODO *nodoQuad = current->next;
                    current->next = nodoQuad->next;
                    free(nodoQuad);
                    puts( "Element deleted!" );
                } 
                else 
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why insert is not correct?For me works

Comment: @DanieleSadun At least because it does not set the data member next to NULL of the created node.

Comment: @DanieleSadun Set initially the pointer head in main to NULL and call your function insert and see the result. Nothing will be added to the list.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow as always very helpful, especially with the lists!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    /* removeDuplicate() will remove duplicate nodes from the list */
void removeDuplicate(NODO *self) {
    /* Node current will point to head  */
    NODO *current = self->head;  
    NODO *index = NULL;  
    NODO *temp = NULL;  
          
    if(self->head == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        while(current != None) {
            /* Node temp will point to previous node to index */
            temp = current;  
            /* Index will point to node next to current */
            index = current->next;  
                  
            while(index != NULL) {
                /* If current node's data is equal to index node's data */
                if(current->data == index->data) {
                    /* Here, index node is pointing to the node which is duplicate of current node */
                    /* Skips the duplicate node by pointing to next node */
                    temp->next = index->next;  
                } else { 
                    /* Temp will point to the previous node of the index. */
                    temp = index;  
                }
                index = index->next;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to write similar as above for your code's needs.

Comment: Used cpp conditions but the logic is the same. It is not needed to do always copy paste from the answer.

Comment: cpp? `def` and the comments don't look like cpp to me.

Comment: I think it is useful even if it is not the exact program for copy paste and run! It is easy to understand the logic and put some effort to make it as you want. I also did mention it under the code.

Comment: @Example person I think what you wrote is clear and useful! Well done, nice job!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good function to delete duplicates also with the help of other users.
This is the code:

```
void deleteDuplicates(NODO* head) {
        while(head != NULL && head->next != NULL) {
            NODO* nodoQuad = head;
            while(nodoQuad->next != NULL) {
            if(head->q.lato == nodoQuad->next->q.lato &&
               head->q.v.x == nodoQuad->next->q.v.x &&
               head->q.v.y == nodoQuad->next->q.v.y) {
                   NODO* dealloca = nodoQuad->next;
                   nodoQuad->next = nodoQuad->next->next
                   free(dealloca);
                   printf("Element deleted!\n");
               } else {
                   nodoQuad = nodoQuad->next;
               }
        }
        head = head->next;
        }
}
```